# Does the cp cap max out at level 30?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know that the max cp of a Pokemon increases with your trainer level. Recently my friend told me that this increase is only until level 30.

I couldn't find anything contrary to this so I'm asking if anyone knows if this is true or not.

Does the cp cap not increase past level 30?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, currently, the max CP wild pokemon you can encounter, really maxes out at Level 30. After that the cap is Level 40, but you can reach that trough upgrading the Pokemon only, any wild pokemon will have the same cap Level 30+.

Also this is true to date. It is quite possible they up the cap later down to road, or even in December when they are allegedly adding Gen2 (rumor)

[image]

[Some more sources](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2016/07/23/data-miners-have-allegedly-uncovered-pokemon-go-deepest-secrets.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It does until level 40, that seems to be the maximum.

You can check it here: https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884#file-pokemon-go-data-dump-txt-L618 (line 574)